# LInux disk has directory permissions and attributes d????????? ??

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server

I have an external enclosure of four 4Tb hard drives on an Ubuntu 18.04 server, just configured as a JBOD, one of the drives being just archives that have another backup offline (thank God). I tried to access one of the directories on this drive in a terminal and got "Cannot allocate memory". Looking at the directory listing, about half the directories have attributes of d????????? ? ? ? ? ?, appearing to be random directories. I tried to change the permissions using "sudo chmod -R 755" and get "Read-only file system error" for all of the questionable directories and subdirectories. Anyone know what would cause this? The other three drives are OK for now, but I really need to know what the cause is.

Hopefully an excerpt from the `ls -l` output will help explain:

```
drwxr-xr-x 27 rob rob      4096 Apr  2 01:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 rob rob      4096 Mar 19 16:43 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 rob rob  57724928 Feb 15 04:10 20081026-183841.MPG*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 rob rob        20 Feb 15 04:10 ArcDeviceInfo*
drwxr-xr-x 27 rob rob      4096 Mar 22 04:18 Archives/
d?????????  ? ?   ?           ?            ? back081215/
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob rob      4096 Feb 15 05:19 Christmas 2001 CD Project/
d?????????  ? ?   ?           ?            ? Collected online data/
d?????????  ? ?   ?           ?            ? Downloads_180101/
d?????????  ? ?   ?           ?            ? Downloads_180201/
drwxr-xr-x 12 rob rob      4096 Feb 15 07:35 _exempt/
drwxrwxr-x  2 rob rob      4096 Feb 15 08:02 Fedora downloads/
```

`

Comment: I think it mounted in read only. Post the contents of the fstab.

Comment: Mm, not buying that, as this drive has been in use for several months since installing it. But here's the line from fstab:


`UUID=f401b604-b2bd-4b79-bec7-e99b33386545 /media/MoreStore      ext4    defaults        0       0`

Comment: check /proc/mounts and post that back. Also, I would umount and run fsck on it.

Comment: None of that info is available now, as I deleted the partition and restored the backups, needing to move on. I had tried fsck when this first showed up, but I didn't note the wording of the results. I do remember it was a brief one-liner that said nothing clear about the state of the filesystem. That was about the point that I posted my question.
I was hoping that someone would have seen this signature before. Some incident corrupted this drive, and the mystery is that it's (1) in an external enclosure with three other uncorrupted drives, and (2) on a UPS.